# Accessing RDS in private subnet with port forwarding via Terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to establish a connection to my rds in a private subnet via a Bastion host. I can access the Bastion host via SSH without problem and have opened up the security group in the private subnet where the RDS DB is located for incoming traffic from the bastion host security group. 
now there are 2 possibilities to connect to the RDS Instance. 
Solution 1. install MySQL commndline tool on the bastion host and use it to connect to the RDS DB
Solution 2. access the RDS via port forwarding from my local computer.

I can connect via MySQL commanding from the Bastion Host but struggle to get the port forwarding going. When I’m using

```
ssh -i ecs_key.pem  -NL 3007:mydb3.co2qgzotzpzu.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ubuntu@ec2-56-18-172-97.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

i end up being on the bastion Host as well. Can anybody explain to me if there is a difference between those 2 solutions or should I stick with solution 1 which works for me.

Merci A

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect on localhost:3007, not 9000

Comment: do you mean it like that: ```mysql -h localhost P 3007 -u RDS_USER -p```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two solutions is that in solution 1, you have to install the mysql command line tool on the bastion, whereas with a tunnel (solution 2) you can use tools on your computer to connect via the tunnel.

I prefer to not clutter the bastion host with tools that I already have locally. Best practices for a bastion host is to minimize the attack surface by only installing the minimum sshd configuration to allow you to set up the tunnel, and not install a bunch of dev tools.

Likewise if you want install a SQL studio tool like Workbench or Dbeaver, you will want to use it locally, and connect via the the tunnel.

Your tunnel set up looks correct. Stick with it.

Try:

'mysql  --host=127.0.0.1  --port=3007 --user=myname --password'

NOTE 
When localhost is given for the host parameter, MySQL uses sockets and ignores the port settings. Use 127.0.0.1 instead. See 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html

Comment: merci; but when I try ```ssh -i ar_ecs_key.pem  -NL 3007:mydb3.co2qgzotzpzu.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ubuntu@ec2-56-18-172-97.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com``` i dont get anything, the cursor just stays...nothing is happening. that not normal I presume...

Comment: what ports do I need to open on the rds and on the bastion host. so far I have opened port 22 on the bastion host only and allow traffic from the bastion host security group in the rds security group. but that doesnt seem to work...